# Is there a cudaminer difficulty parameter option

Tags: mining-pools, stratum, cex.io

I try to mine some btc using cudaminer on cex.io.
I'm using cudaminer for that. I have a lot 'low' rejected shares due to low difficulty (On the ghash.io they say the minimum stratum difficulty is 16).

I think my rejected shares is due to this difficulty but I dunno if I can change that on my side to avoid rejected shares.

Any idea?

Comment: You should consider mining on their scrypt multipool and converting the earnings to BTC. You will earn MUCH more vs. mining BTC directly. You can change the difficulty of scrypt miners to a setting below 16. The minimum of 16 is for their BTC pool. To change it, go to the ghash.io page and click on the currency you are mining. After you load the page for the correct currency, click the workers link at the top and there will be a spot to edit individual worker difficulty. In that spot you can set the difficulty lower than 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Difficulty is handled server-side rather than client-side.

Different pools have different policies regarding difficulty. Some pools have a fixed difficulty. Others automatically calibrate the difficulty depending on your hashrate (this is called vardiff). And some let you set the difficulty, on the pool website. But in any case, it is ultimately the stratum that sends out and accepts work, so it is the pool that dictates difficulty.

Comment: THanks for answer. I was asking this because some pools offer us to set the difficulty ourselves but they use cgminer as example where you can set the difficulty with -d param.
Btw, thanks !